# Pirate Treasure

Tags: code-golf

Finding a treasure hidden by pirates is really easy. Everything you need for this is a map. It is widely known that pirates draw maps by hand and describe the algorithm to find a place in the following way: "Stand near a lone palm tree, do 30 steps towards the forest, 15 towards the lake, ..."

A journey through such route is usually a great opportunity to see the scenery... However, nowadays nobody has time for that. That's why treasure seekers have asked you to write a program that would determine the exact location of a treasure using a given map.

---

## Input

The input consists of multiple instructions `<Direction> <Distance>`, separated with commas (that are followed by one whitespace each).

**Direction** is one of the following:
**`N`** - North, **`S`** - South, **`E`** - East, **`W`** - West,
**`NE`** - Northeast, **`NW`** - Northwest, **`SE`** - Southeast, **`SW`** - Southwest.

**Distance** is an integer (1 to 1000).

## Output

The result is the coordinates where you end up after finishing the instructions, with three decimal places, separated with a comma and a whitespace. Start location has zero coordinates (0, 0).

The first coordinate is **X** (East means coordinates larger than zero, West means less than zero).
The second coordinate is **Y** (North means *more* than zero, South means *less* than zero).

---

## Examples

**1.** `N 3, E 1, N 1, E 3, S 2, W 1`

`3.000, 2.000`

**2.** `NW 10`

`-7.071, 7.071`

**3.** `NE 42, NW 42, SE 42, SW 42`

`0.000, 0.000`

---

<sup>[Source](http://acm.lviv.ua/fusion/viewpage.php?page_id=9&id=1016) (in Ukrainian). Input format is different there.</sup>

Comment: Bonus points for doing it in Logo? ;)

Comment: @Peter The output format is strict... But we will see whether people like the picture :D

Comment: The first example output should be `-3.000, 2.000`.

Comment: with UCB Logo the output format can be obtained as `(print (word (form xcor 4 3) ",) (form ycor 4 3))`. But I'm not sure how easy parsing the input would be.

Comment: @Lowjacker Yes, thanks. Actually, the input was wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Ruby 1.9, <strike>175</strike> <strike>171</strike> <strike>162</strike> <strike>153</strike> <strike>130</strike> <strike>120</strike> 117

```
l=0
gets.scan(/(\w+) (\d+)/){|d,n|l+=n.to_i*?i.to_c**%w[E NE N NW W SW S SE].index(d).quo(2)}
puts'%.3f, %.3f'%l.rect
```

Comment: `?i.to_c` can be shortened to `1.i` for -4 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, <strike>158</strike> <strike>154</strike> 150 chars

```
p=0j
for s in raw_input().split(','):c,d=s.split();v=sum(dict(N=1j,E=1,S=-1j,W=-1)[x]for x in c);p+=v*int(d)/abs(v)
print'%.3f, %.3f'%(p.real,p.imag)
```

Comment: You actually have 157 chars, not 158.

Comment: I guess I don't need to, but I usually count the trailing newline.

Comment: [157] Line 1: `D=dict(N=1j,E=1,S=-1j,W=-1)` [153] Line 2: is `j` really needed? [152] Lines 3-4: If you switch to Python 3, `raw_input`→`input`, and even though you have to use parentheses after `print`, you save 2 characters [150]

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Thanks for the dict optimization.  The j is needed in line 2 in case all the directions are E and W.  The resulting p needs to be complex for `.real` and `.imag` to work.

Comment: @Keith: It is not necessary to even declare the dict. You can just put it instead of D inside the code to save 4 more characters. Just saying...

Comment: int class has both `imag` and `real` attrs...

Comment: @JBernardo: well, not in my python version (2.4.4).

Comment: @Keith: there is really no reason to use that version of Python.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell (291)

```
import Text.Printf
d=sqrt(0.5)
f"N"n(x,y)=(x,y+n)
f"S"n(x,y)=(x,y-n)
f"E"n(x,y)=(x+n,y)
f"W"n(x,y)=(x-n,y)
f[a,b]n(x,y)=(s,t)where(s,_)=f[b](d*n)(x,y);(_,t)=f[a](d*n)(x,y)
p[]=(0,0)
p(a:b:c)=f a(read b::Float)$p c
s(a,b)=printf"%.3f, %.3f"a b
main=getLine>>=putStrLn.s.p.words.filter(/=',')
```

Comment: How about changing the defintion of f to use pattern guards? They have the nice property to not require a line break and should be more breve in this case. Also, use interact.

Answer (score 4):

### C99 (319 chars)

```
#define B ;break;
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
float x,y,w,z,j;int
main(void){int
k;char
c[3];while(scanf("%s%d,",c,&k)==2){j=k;w=1;switch(c[1]){case'E':w=3;default:w-=2;j=sqrt(k*k/2)B
case
0:w=z=0;}switch(*c){case'N':z=1
B
case'S':z=-1
B
case'E':w=1
B
default:w=-1;}x+=w*j;y+=z*j;}printf("%5.3f, %5.3f\n",x,y);}
```

input in `stdin`, [test run](http://ideone.com/HNj3d) at ideone :)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, <del>179</del> <del>164</del> <del>170</del> <del>168</del> <del>158</del> <del>156</del> 153 chars

```
prompt(X=Y=0).replace(/(N|S)?(.)? (\d+)/g,
        function(m,y,x,n){
            n/=x&&y?Math.SQRT2:1
            Y+=y?y<'S'?n:-n:0
            X+=x?x<'W'?n:-n:0
        })
alert(X.toFixed(3)+', '+Y.toFixed(3))
```

- 170: fixed accuracy issue
- 168: replaced `(E|W)` in regex with `(.)`
- 158: replaced repetitive logic in function with variable `d`
- 156: reused `n` instead of a new variable `d`
- 153: Personally, I think this edit makes it ten times uglier, but it's three characters shorter. It's based on the non-standard behavior that you can call RegExp objects as functions: `/./g('string')` is the same as `/./g.exec('string')`:

  `for(p=prompt(X=Y=0),R=/(N|S)?(.)? (\d+)/g;[,y,x,n]=R(p)||0;X+=x?x<'W'?n:-n:0)n/=x&&y?Math.SQRT2:1,Y+=y?y<'S'?n:-n:0;alert(X.toFixed(3)+', '+Y.toFixed(3))`

Comment: Unfortunately, q=.707 fails the "NW 10" input due to rounding errors; I think you need "q=Math.SQRT1_2" which adds 8 chars. On the other hand, you can replace "(E|W)?" with "(.)?" since you have already established north/south/neither and the input is well-formed, saving 2 chars.

Comment: Thanks for the regex bit. As for the accuracy issue, I used SQRT2 instead and switched the multiplication to division.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 199 characters

```
import Text.Printf
import Complex
i=0:+(1::Float)
e 'S'= -i
e d=i^mod(fromEnum d-1)4
g p(d:s:t)=g(p+(signum.sum.map e)d*(fst(reads s!!0):+0))t
g(x:+y)[]=printf"%.3f, %.3f"x y
main=interact$g 0.words
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scala (<strike>367</strike>, 332)**

```
var (x,y,s)=(.0,.0,.7071);args.mkString(" ").split(",").foreach{m=>val a=m.trim.split(" ");var (n,u,v)=(a(1).toInt,.0,.0);a(0) match{case "N"=>v=1;case "S"=>v= -1;case "E"=>u=1;case "W"=>u= -1;case "NW"=>{u= -s;v=s};case "NE"=>{u=s;v=s};case "SW"=>{u= -s;v= -s};case "SE"=>{u=s;v= -s}};x += n*u;y += n*v};printf("%1.3f %1.3f\n",x,y)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java <s>(459) (445) (402) (382) (363)</s> (352)

```java
import java.util.*;class
M{public
static void main(String[]a){double
x=0,y=0;Scanner
s=new
Scanner(System.in);s.useDelimiter("\\W+");while(s.hasNext()){String
d=s.next();double
z=Math.sqrt(d.length());int
w=s.nextInt();y+=(d.contains("N")?w:d.contains("S")?-w:0)/z;x+=(d.contains("E")?w:d.contains("W")?-w:0)/z;}System.out.format("%1.3f %1.3f",x,y);}}
```

stdin input

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 178

```
$input-split','|%{,@{N=0,1
NE=($s=.707106781186548),$s
E=1,0
SE=$s,-$s
S=0,-1
SW=-$s,-$s
W=-1,0
NW=-$s,$s}[($a=-split$_)[0]]*$a[1]}|%{$x+=$_[0]
$y+=$_[1]}
'{0:N3}, {1:N3}'-f$x,$y
```

This can probably lose up to 10 characters by reducing the accuracy of √2/2.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>155</s> 152 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
float x,y,l;D;main(d){for(;scanf("%s%f,",&d,&l)>0;y+=d^78?d^83?0:-l:l)D=d,l/=D>99?D/=256,d&=255,sqrt(2):1,x+=D^87?D^69?0:l:-l;printf("%.3f, %.3f",x,y);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5NC4JAFEX/ykNIHHpmKubHMLqZtm1atBOGGSaEl5W6UKK/3qSbc7mLw706vGvtnKWnmmDGBYlL/lBdHxj2sc8h4KNWvQ283biz6KFv0CdWH/myF6bNi8a0Rdocq5AqYlIYpEjIuiwbGYkkO6Hx18hwfA9TkLAqxnkvZFvkjWxP5erRavLX0PXTtnFILcJGD9cvjH@du0CKcIYY4bLhvNUrJAg3iH/akrqPLqTHHw)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy (215)

```
x=0.0;y=0.0;args.join(' ').split(', ').each{d=it.split(' ');c=d[0]==~/../?Math.sqrt(2):1;s=d[1] as int;a=['N':1,'S':-1,'E':1,'W':-1];m=d[0]=~/N|S/;y+=m?a[m[0]]*(s/c):0;m=d[0]=~/E|W/;x+=m?s/c*a[m[0]]:0};print "$x,$y"
```

reads input as program arguments. Example:

```
groovy golf.groovy NW 10, SW 10, W 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 122 bytes

```perl
s,(N|S)?(E|W)? (\d+),$d=$3/($1&$2?2**.5:1);$x+=$2&&$d*(-1)**($2gt F);$y+=$1&&$d*(-1)**($1gt O),ge;printf"%.3f, %.3f",$x,$y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VckxDoMgFADQqxDzawCB@jEuNYap3WqHDl06osbEIFEGTTx7qR27vOX5dh7LGBdBm/3JDL3uL2YIfduMCbA1FGcKmII2mnNVXpBVsGY16DQFy6lExjkF3QdyO2Y7Bv8Gj3kw0beVnwcXuuSkik6Qn4mAVcAWY0Mw/0w@DJNboryXKsc8SvcF)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 93 bytes

```
[:0j3&":@+.@(1#.".@>@{:*(0j1^2%~i.8){~<;._1@' E NE N NW W SW S SE'i.{.)@|:[:(<;._1);._1', ',]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU3BqsJADLz3K4aKptU1ZFtBWX2y8Kgn8eAePIh6EEV78QMq/npftvoePEgmGTKTqduU6YovB4KBwGmPGd/b9ardO6nLQer8iH1me5yyX/rGDTOp7bHov@48y5vXYs4n6wkVNlrY7LBD0EKo6M4N5/7p9i7rZHkEMiBzaPPkcr49QKcpy9SiQ8LY4QrSJ1boIyhZRFBE/LujNBpojQbauCkNKIxG21@bdDb5Z6swUZF@jyO8WYiMkqT9AQ)