# Be My Navigator

Tags: code-golf

Oh no, I am lost on the way to finding the great treasures of Marakov! And all I have are these useless instructions that look like `S10R10D30`... I have no idea what they mean! Can you help me?

### Challenge

Given directions consisting of `N E S W U D L R 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`, output how far I will be from where I started when I follow those directions (i.e. Euclidean Distance).

`N E S W` refer to me turning North, East, South, and West;

`U D L R` refer to me turning Up, Down, Left, and Right (So `NR` is the same as `E`, and so is `SL`; `SLL` is the same as `N`). Up means keep going forward; Down means turn around.

After each letter direction will be a number, which is how far I will go in that direction. `N10E20` means go North 10 units, then turn East, and go East 20 units.

### Input Details

- Input will always start with one of `NESW` (so blank input need not be accounted for).
- Two letter instructions in a row are allowed. `NE` should be interpreted, "Turn North, then immediately turn East". It's the same as just `E`. `SLL` is "Turn South, then immediately turn Left twice". It's the same as `N`.
- All numbers will be integers (note how `.` isn't in the character set)
- Input will only consist of `NESWUDLR1234567890` (If it *needs* something else, like '\0' in C; or if your language's input functions has a trailing newline, or something, that's fine.)

### Output

- [The norm.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- If using a function, should output a numeric datatype or a string.
- Must be accurate to 3 decimal places.

### Test Cases

- `N10`: `10`
- `N10E10`: `14.1421`
- `N10S10`: `0`
- `NSEWUDLR10`: `10`
- `N100RR20E300D40L12`: `268.7452`
- `ERR10LL20UN30D100`: `70.71067`

[The unimaginative Python program I used to make these.](https://tio.run/##fZLLboMwEEXX8VeM3E1IWtWQ9IWUVcMOeUGEWERRlQbSIqU4MqRSv57OOA8IKF5gaXyP597B3v9V36qY1DXLi7LSh02Vq6KEGfAgilwRhp6I5UTMXSE4u2bGCMWcbVKkpSoygDt4P2idFRWkuc4MxorDzye1E5x0iVWmoayUXn9lbKOUTsltKe5BrNhWaUAP/KBt5bNBvj0L3PUm06fnl9c3wVEYGAPMgjIbZLsWKINFEs/D6IJ9/K53QGQ1pNI5nzbxsMCzNA2WkvtwDLd0V9T9fBwp43HiFlfcw00uaThh44Irru17jNcejdAUToM3k8/MtfiwX5e9/bn5Fd05qQlOQkpvNqPJnnYxx8RdLbhoCe8GCG8HSCwmtnC2ALIXILodwNbIFsAWHAOwvaYHd7xV51QNm0sejcCDcesV0YZD69B99Bynrv8B)

### Winning

This is codegolf, so lowest bytes after a week wins!

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Right. Lemme edit.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2442/42963)

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Also [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32037/lets-move-the-mars-rover), but all are slightly different.

Comment: Can we assume the input consists only of `NESWUDLR1234567890`?

Comment: @darrylyeo Sure, let me edit.

Comment: I thought Logo would be a cute language to submit this in, with the following search and replace pairs: `N` → `seth 0 fd `, `E` → `seth 90 fd `, `S` → `seth 180 fd `, `W` → `seth 270 fd `, `U` → `fd `, `D` → `fd -`, `L` → `lt 90 fd `, `R` → `rt 90 fd `; then `split`, `run` and `print sqrt (xcor ^ 2 + ycor ^ 2)` to get the normal. Alas, Logo has no search and replace string operations!

Comment: @YiminRong Perhaps Python search and replace + [this Python logo interp](https://github.com/dominoanty/Logo-Interpreter) (if ext. libraries are allowed in ppcg)? Or any other comparable language!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [(Go)Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 111 bytes

```ruby
x=0
c=1,1i,-1,-1i
gs.sc(/(\w)(\d*)/){|o,a|x+=c.ro!('URDL'.ix(o)||'NESW'.ix(o)+c.ix(1)).fs*a.toi}
p Mh::hy *x.rc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVZtb9s2EP7uX3Gxg1hyXNnu9smokRZr1g1oMyDFMGBpJlAUbbOlRIGkEjuW89ezIynJjusWHRYY0eneX54jpcpk/dTrwQepDcg5mCUDuiT5gmmkiYF3UqEKZOQLcuZKZqDYohREgeV3OlQQreGP5DOjpgPw@vVCinm8JHoJM9hsO8hL2RwyZpYyjTOuNc8XkA1hQIZwlqAYwKDqnuEN3KBcMzGPnPdbuIWqmmEOhi7ROvbOdJCFN@Nb54Fj5nB2Bt4fQBxrlqdxHBgbKIRNNSBqoataDJBECc9TdBaxOyKCbqEk3VQuBRcmJYZUcPqImT1nwrYbRpQIEZw@hjbu6eOeUydwocKau3VPJjSrGQYuDtKzfQhhCrosmPLqedrx/5v2HZauMbF@fwgZPm1QkgjWCH1ohZLRP72NjoyMdbTQZRKMolG46QbR4CLswjlcswVbFRHTlBQsOD0Lt9uRs82ihWJFoMJIS2VinH8qoeJN@7h36ZKySmhuSsUspwjOppo/sBBevQJ@vBg/WZlr0@KBfgMHdPgDMKBDcN5IbnSLCAMkTxGrmFjuxfGCmcDUzSFcM7giGbtUSqohdMuc59xwIjD5tPUHvQ3ddoeuxUwFk/CgkiW2h6FrkiSK3XFiuMx/YDZWw8/FvcpSxZRgQjMILt5E0cXfIcxmqLIH7yxCvLJV4M3WWYOvSVQWRiLbdX1TPVToGQeau2FjmzMEus/rIbQD2lRGYZm7VcjZykCZC4Z7HDyL7xQxB/vWJtnaOSkMbK0tr@63F/EjuHUSbI2dk6vEutbNrny1LDkXxzF02Fff1hYr1qs/k3DbahUEfKH4HTGtEe7czrx2Xqs0cZYBsdP8DceZWOIeCWqJk76fQFEaDd3ehmyZEHKIgEm2UonUAWfnFnFFNGiydgaN91TG90sufLVjcDSsORMH1aJemZu6F2Nw9DM9p@srf6MUWbcRpUhj1@YabJ7rOJ8lz/cNfyXY918s@U1rm0uL2m736@C/5wbPFNU6YIQuwfCMWROeU1GmDC7zMmPKTm/f9CNCI1@0liPQheCms4tK/IwtN@j39zYxcCXjftiVpbvpvoAjrJupdaXWQ5gaRXJdSM2QngtiDMt31AmSuDwFoWZHWSbmKvHEmSpH3IaRrXFT2Qh@p@yFAl1H2sx7Gyva@lvBHvVC0i/N9lpwtaXZ9dGlsKcgib5rhoezIJQFJLJDbLi4b97BbgcaMPi/ejput70mbiEuSG2FFX4J@nTQt5dRzXMg8da4lkci1MM0Uu0dAk7FXwYuQbvpDBV3ntiBdiNxe@6etoPbfYA8i3Qcn/8RCXUbb/FkcLDQ/3OadpLfG1xb1X7@mFlhz6n62coaflPjs11ZZ4kUe0fhsWj2k8bd24rRu6pFDr2L2s8Pe2DaL5Bjme6W@2k1G3fobDKc8OGLCf54Z2HvmGAUfLoPg0/pIMTPikoOSbU6n9FIyZOg/@f12/f9iK8CGVZV/@ry41/12zm1z0kYRnM9IIgMvu0U8GE5nS7XMFhFij49XU3G4@vrl@PLn8bjtz@P309e/gs)

Takes input on STDIN, outputs it on STDOUT.

Basically, this approach uses complex numbers to store the current position, as well as a stack (`c`), containing offsets for each direction. If a direction is in `URDL`, the stack is rotated by the index of the direction in that string; if the direction is in `NESW`, it's rotated by the index of the direction in that string, plus the index of `1` in the stack. This transforms a rotation relative to the current position into a rotation relative to the position of 1. In any event, the top of the stack is multiplied by the number of steps in the direction and added to the current position.

Comment: What's "(Go)Ruby"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's Ruby, where the interpreter has been compiled with a special flag that makes it more suitable for golfing. Among other changes, it allows you to abbreviate method names, and changes the behavior of certain built-ins. If you visit my TiO link, you'll see the code in the header, which is the majority of changes that are made.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 137 bytes

```python
v=n=0
d=1
for i in input()+'U':x="NUERSDW0123456789".find(i);c=x<7;v+=d*n*c;n=[n*10+x-7,0][c];d=[d,d**(x%2)*1j**(~-x/2)][c]
print(abs(v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBC4IwGIDhu79ChHCbWt9mZbV205t4MKSDeCiHtA5TzGRd@uvL4D088A6f6dHr2NpZaAGOFNTp@tFVrtJLw3tCOPAr/2SEV1RZeUmvQFm83e2Tw9Fbd0pLpDBvhTknfA6EJJq0XItaEwqBiZIQmrptuBS1DCUhyKwYJvS56BuZDcP/6wyj0hO63V9oxtjarCwp5DmDqoghpQA/)

-9 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: You can save six bytes with the else clause: `else:v+=d*n;n=0;h='NUERSDW'.find(i);d=d**(h%2)*1j**(~-h/2)`- note that `L` can be lopped off the end of the find string here because `-1%2` equals `7%2` and `1j**(-1)` equals `1j**3`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice tricks! Thanks!

Comment: Save another three by inlining the for: `for i in input()+'U':x="NUERSDW0123456789".find(i);c=x<7;v+=d*n*c;n=[n*10+x-7,0][c];d=[d,d**(x%2)*1j**(~-x/2)][c]`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Hey cool, thanks!

Comment: Tried my own hand at a Python answer, couldn't get below 179 bytes. Bravo.

Comment: @Quelklef Thanks! Did you try using complex numbers? They're very useful for challenges about 2D coordinates because for distance you can just do `abs(coords)` and you can rotate by multiplying by `1j` or `-1j`.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yeah, I stole that from you as well as your `.find` instead of `.index` trick... Just couldn't make it. I Think the fundamental difference lies in your use of `"NUERSDW0123456789".find(i)`. I have no idea what that does (conceptually).

Comment: @Quelklef If `x < 7` then it's a direction; otherwise, it's a number. It serves to act as a conditional without an `if` statement (to avoid needing indentation). It also serves to modify the current number of the instruction and to give the index of the command.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Ah, it's not as complicated as I though. I think we went for similar approaces (I, too, had a negative/positive * complex/non-complex * scalar) but you just golfed better =]

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>148</s> <s>142</s> <s>140</s> <s>138</s> <s>137</s> 134 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/\d+|./g,_=>~(i='NESW'.search(_))?d=i:~(i='URDL'.search(_))?d+=i:a[d&3]+=+_,a=[0,0,0,0])&&Math.hypot(a[1]-a[3],a[0]-a[2])
```

```js
f=

s=>s.replace(/\d+|./g,_=>~(i='NESW'.search(_))?d=i:~(i='URDL'.search(_))?d+=i:a[d&3]+=+_,a=[0,0,0,0])&&Math.hypot(a[1]-a[3],a[0]-a[2])

for(test of [
  'N10',
  'N10E10',
  'N10S10',
  'NSEWUDLR10',
  'N100RR20E300D40L12',
  'ERR10LL20UN30D100',
]) console.log(f(test))
```

-2 bytes: Use `.search()` instead of `.indexOf()` ([@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137235/be-my-navigator/137241?noredirect=1#comment335996_137241))

-1 byte: Rearrange program to remove enclosing parentheses ([@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137235/be-my-navigator/137241?noredirect=1#comment335998_137241))

-3 bytes: Use `.replace()` instead of `.match().map()` ([@ThePirateBay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137235/be-my-navigator/137241?noredirect=1#comment336036_137241))

Comment: We're getting different answers for the second-to-last test.

Comment: @Quelklef Fixed.

Comment: Can you save a couple of bytes using `search` instead of `indexOf`?

Comment: I think you can also save a byte by moving `a` into the `map`, replacing the `,` before `Math` with `&&` and removing the enclosing parentheses.

Comment: @Shaggy Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by replacing `match(...).map(...)` with `replace`.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 149 + 1 (-p) = 150 bytes

```perl
while(s/(\D+)(\d+)//){$p=/N/?0:/E/?1:/S/?2:/W/?3:/L/?$p-1:/R/?$p+1:/D/?$p+2:$p for split//,$1;$m[$p%4]+=$2}$_=sqrt(($m[0]-$m[2])**2+($m[1]-$m[3])**2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcixDoIwFEDRX2GoSUut77XIUkO6wIYMGOMgxEWMJCgVSByMv24tLDc3xzZDFzv3vrddQ0egVcoZra6cAbAPsQkUYFBDBkZqOIBRGk5gIg05GGKFx3Ie7iddRmlig1s/BKPt2glgTeSOPM7ErrY1T4j6kksyvoaJUq9YC19VszBUfAa5QLQAcy4rS4l5rvBYRJhKxF9vp7Z/jk7s4w1KdML@AQ)

**Explained:**

```perl
# Each direction is assigned a number:
#
#     0     North
#     1     East
#     2     South
#     3     West
#
# Variables:
#     $p     present direction
#     @m     total movement in each direction
# Inside loop:
#     $1     a set of direction instructions
#     $2     distance

while(s/(\D+)(\d+)//)    # Remove and preserve the first direction set and distance
   for split//,$1        # Loop through individual letters to set new direction
      $p=/N/?0:          # North
         /E/?1:          # South
         /S/?2:          # East
         /W/?3:          # West
         /L/?$p-1:       # Turn left
         /R/?$p+1:       # Turn right
         /D/?$p+2:       # Turn around
         $p              # Do not change direction
   $m[$p%4]+=$2          # Add the directional movement to previous movements

   $_=sqrt(              # Calculate distance
       ($m[0]-$m[2])**2  # Net North/South movement
      +($m[1]-$m[3])**2  # Net East/West movement
      )
```